# Why doesn't this change of variables work?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to calculate the infinite sum of odd terms of $\zeta(2)$ as follows. Setting $2k-1 = \ell$ yields $k = (\ell+1)/2$ and so

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^{2}} = \sum_{\frac{l+1}{2}=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\ell^{2}}  = \sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ell^{2}} = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6}.$$

This is obviously nonsense if you instead try splitting up $\zeta(2)$ into its even and odd terms.

Experience shifting indices without problem seems to suggest that it's the division by 2 that is causing the issue, but its not obvious to me what is wrong. Is there an abuse of notation when using the $=$ symbol in the infinite sum that is making this operation invalid or is there something else going on?

Comment: in the first sum, you are going over the odd indices only. In the third sum, you are going over all natural numbers. Your second equality is erroneous

Comment: Your new variable just run over the *odd* positive integers *not* over *all* positive integers, that is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{\frac{\ell+1}{2}=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\ell^{2}}  = \sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ell^{2}}$$
is the problem. The left is perfectly valid if you solve the equations
$$\frac{\ell+1}{2}=1\qquad\frac{\ell+1}{2}=2\qquad\frac{\ell+1}{2}=3\qquad\ldots$$for $\ell$. But you substituted $\ell$ in the place of $\frac{\ell+1}{2}$ on the right which gives the equations
$$\ell=1\qquad\ell=2\qquad\ell=3\qquad\ldots$$
Though the first equation may give the correct value for $\ell$, the remaining ones do not. Thus you get the wrong answer because
$$\ell \neq \frac{\ell+1}{2}$$

Comment: Seeing the indices as a set of equations $(\ell+1)/2 = 1, (\ell+1)/2 = 2, \dots$ helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I should clarify for the sake of any future readers that I didn't substitute $(\ell+1)/2$ for $\ell$. I took the equation $(\ell+1)/2 = 1$ and solved for $\ell$ in the lower index.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my comment, if you want to calculate the first sum, we think of it as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k)^2} = \zeta(2)-\frac 14 \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$$